# Minimum output value for NSSound setVolume: method (Cocoa / ObjC)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

New member (long time lurker) and first question here...

Currently I am building a cocoa app that allows a user to set the volume of an NSSound using a slider.

```
-(IBAction)setVolume:(id)sender{

    //sender is the slider
    [mySound setVolume:[sender floatValue]];

}
```

I've noticed that there seems to be a cutoff for how small a float the [sender floatValue] can return before the sound is no longer output from the speakers / headphones. Specifically, this value is 1e-3.

Going from 9e-4 to 1e-3 for the slider value creates a noticeable "pop" and the sound can be heard. Reverse the order and the sound can no longer be heard.

I have tried digging through the documentation for NSSound and NSSound.h to no avail. Has anyone else noticed this issue EDIT: and know how to increase the sensitivity of setVolume?

NOTE: The sounds being played are pure sine waves and this behavior is consistent across the 63 - 10 kHz spectrum.

USING:
PowerBook G4
OSX 10.5.8
XCode 3.1.3